# Number text recognition not highlighting/recognizing text

Tags: ios, swift, vision, text-recognition

I am following the [apple phone number recognition sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/reading_phone_numbers_in_real_time). Normally it creates a red outline around the recognized text. Mine does not seem to do recognizing the text and creating the red outline even though I used their code. The only difference is my view controller class is called "TextScanViewController" where their's is just "ViewController". I went through and made sure that any "ViewControllers" were changed to "TextScanViewController". Am I missing something else that I should change?

Here is what it should look like (when I use the original Apple project) compared to what it is doing (should have red outlines but is not showing them even if the text is perfectly in the center of the rectangle)

Should look like:
[image]

Looks like:
[image]

There are 5 different swift files I am using (PreviewView, TextScanViewController, VisionViewController, StringUtils, AppDelegate)

TextScanViewController:

```
    import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class TextScanViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - UI objects
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cutoutView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberView: UILabel!
    var maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    // Device orientation. Updated whenever the orientation changes to a
    // different supported orientation.
    var currentOrientation = UIDeviceOrientation.portrait
    
    // MARK: - Capture related objects
    private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.apple-samplecode.CaptureSessionQueue")
    
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    
    var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    let videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.apple-samplecode.VideoDataOutputQueue")
    
    // MARK: - Region of interest (ROI) and text orientation
    // Region of video data output buffer that recognition should be run on.
    // Gets recalculated once the bounds of the preview layer are known.
    var regionOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    // Orientation of text to search for in the region of interest.
    var textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.up
    
    // MARK: - Coordinate transforms
    var bufferAspectRatio: Double!
    // Transform from UI orientation to buffer orientation.
    var uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    // Transform bottom-left coordinates to top-left.
    var bottomToTopTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -1)
    // Transform coordinates in ROI to global coordinates (still normalized).
    var roiToGlobalTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    
    // Vision -> AVF coordinate transform.
    var visionToAVFTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    
    // MARK: - View controller methods
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set up preview view.
        previewView.session = captureSession
        
        // Set up cutout view.
        cutoutView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        cutoutView.layer.mask = maskLayer
        
        // Starting the capture session is a blocking call. Perform setup using
        // a dedicated serial dispatch queue to prevent blocking the main thread.
        captureSessionQueue.async {
            self.setupCamera()
            
            // Calculate region of interest now that the camera is setup.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Figure out initial ROI.
                self.calculateRegionOfInterest()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        // Only change the current orientation if the new one is landscape or
        // portrait. You can't really do anything about flat or unknown.
        let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        if deviceOrientation.isPortrait || deviceOrientation.isLandscape {
            currentOrientation = deviceOrientation
        }
        
        // Handle device orientation in the preview layer.
        if let videoPreviewLayerConnection = previewView.videoPreviewLayer.connection {
            if let newVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(deviceOrientation: deviceOrientation) {
                videoPreviewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = newVideoOrientation
            }
        }
        
        // Orientation changed: figure out new region of interest (ROI).
        calculateRegionOfInterest()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        updateCutout()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Setup
    
    func calculateRegionOfInterest() {
        // In landscape orientation the desired ROI is specified as the ratio of
        // buffer width to height. When the UI is rotated to portrait, keep the
        // vertical size the same (in buffer pixels). Also try to keep the
        // horizontal size the same up to a maximum ratio.
        let desiredHeightRatio = 0.15
        let desiredWidthRatio = 0.6
        let maxPortraitWidth = 0.8
        
        // Figure out size of ROI.
        let size: CGSize
        if currentOrientation.isPortrait || currentOrientation == .unknown {
            size = CGSize(width: min(desiredWidthRatio * bufferAspectRatio, maxPortraitWidth), height: desiredHeightRatio / bufferAspectRatio)
        } else {
            size = CGSize(width: desiredWidthRatio, height: desiredHeightRatio)
        }
        // Make it centered.
        regionOfInterest.origin = CGPoint(x: (1 - size.width) / 2, y: (1 - size.height) / 2)
        regionOfInterest.size = size
        
        // ROI changed, update transform.
        setupOrientationAndTransform()
        
        // Update the cutout to match the new ROI.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Wait for the next run cycle before updating the cutout. This
            // ensures that the preview layer already has its new orientation.
            self.updateCutout()
        }
    }
    
    func updateCutout() {
        // Figure out where the cutout ends up in layer coordinates.
        let roiRectTransform = bottomToTopTransform.concatenating(uiRotationTransform)
        let cutout = previewView.videoPreviewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: regionOfInterest.applying(roiRectTransform))
        
        // Create the mask.
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: cutoutView.frame)
        path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: cutout))
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        // Move the number view down to under cutout.
        var numFrame = cutout
        numFrame.origin.y += numFrame.size.height
        numberView.frame = numFrame
    }
    
    func setupOrientationAndTransform() {
        // Recalculate the affine transform between Vision coordinates and AVF coordinates.
        
        // Compensate for region of interest.
        let roi = regionOfInterest
        roiToGlobalTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: roi.origin.x, y: roi.origin.y).scaledBy(x: roi.width, y: roi.height)
        
        // Compensate for orientation (buffers always come in the same orientation).
        switch currentOrientation {
        case .landscapeLeft:
            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.up
            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        case .landscapeRight:
            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.down
            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1, y: 1).rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.left
            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1, y: 0).rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
        default: // We default everything else to .portraitUp
            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.right
            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1).rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
        }
        
        // Full Vision ROI to AVF transform.
        visionToAVFTransform = roiToGlobalTransform.concatenating(bottomToTopTransform).concatenating(uiRotationTransform)
    }
    
    func setupCamera() {
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) else {
            print("Could not create capture device.")
            return
        }
        self.captureDevice = captureDevice
        
        // NOTE:
        // Requesting 4k buffers allows recognition of smaller text but will
        // consume more power. Use the smallest buffer size necessary to keep
        // down battery usage.
        if captureDevice.supportsSessionPreset(.hd4K3840x2160) {
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd4K3840x2160
            bufferAspectRatio = 3840.0 / 2160.0
        } else {
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080
            bufferAspectRatio = 1920.0 / 1080.0
        }
        
        guard let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {
            print("Could not create device input.")
            return
        }
        if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
        }
        
        // Configure video data output.
        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange]
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            // NOTE:
            // There is a trade-off to be made here. Enabling stabilization will
            // give temporally more stable results and should help the recognizer
            // converge. But if it's enabled the VideoDataOutput buffers don't
            // match what's displayed on screen, which makes drawing bounding
            // boxes very hard. Disable it in this app to allow drawing detected
            // bounding boxes on screen.
            videoDataOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .off
        } else {
            print("Could not add VDO output")
            return
        }
        
        // Set zoom and autofocus to help focus on very small text.
        do {
            try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
            captureDevice.videoZoomFactor = 2
            captureDevice.autoFocusRangeRestriction = .near
            captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Could not set zoom level due to error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UI drawing and interaction
    
    func showString(string: String) {
        // Found a definite number.
        // Stop the camera synchronously to ensure that no further buffers are
        // received. Then update the number view asynchronously.
        captureSessionQueue.sync {
            self.captureSession.stopRunning()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.numberView.text = string
                self.numberView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        captureSessionQueue.async {
            if !self.captureSession.isRunning {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.numberView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

extension TextScanViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // This is implemented in VisionViewController.
    }
}

// MARK: - Utility extensions

extension AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
    init?(deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {
        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .portrait: self = .portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown: self = .portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeLeft: self = .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeRight: self = .landscapeLeft
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

PreviewView:

```
import Foundation


import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PreviewView: UIView {
    
    
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        guard let layer = layer as? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer else {
            fatalError("Expected `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` type for layer. Check PreviewView.layerClass implementation.")
        }
        
        return layer
    }
    
    var session: AVCaptureSession? {
        get {
            return videoPreviewLayer.session
        }
        set {
            videoPreviewLayer.session = newValue
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: UIView
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
}
```

VisionViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class VisionViewController: TextScanViewController {
    var request: VNRecognizeTextRequest!
    // Temporal string tracker
    let numberTracker = StringTracker()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Set up vision request before letting ViewController set up the camera
        // so that it exists when the first buffer is received.
        request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: recognizeTextHandler)

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Text recognition
    
    // Vision recognition handler.
    func recognizeTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        var numbers = [String]()
        var redBoxes = [CGRect]() // Shows all recognized text lines
        var greenBoxes = [CGRect]() // Shows words that might be serials
        
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
            return
        }
        
        let maximumCandidates = 1
        
        for visionResult in results {
            guard let candidate = visionResult.topCandidates(maximumCandidates).first else { continue }
            
            // Draw red boxes around any detected text, and green boxes around
            // any detected phone numbers. The phone number may be a substring
            // of the visionResult. If a substring, draw a green box around the
            // number and a red box around the full string. If the number covers
            // the full result only draw the green box.
            var numberIsSubstring = true
            
            if let result = candidate.string.extractPhoneNumber() {
                let (range, number) = result
                // Number may not cover full visionResult. Extract bounding box
                // of substring.
                if let box = try? candidate.boundingBox(for: range)?.boundingBox {
                    numbers.append(number)
                    greenBoxes.append(box)
                    numberIsSubstring = !(range.lowerBound == candidate.string.startIndex && range.upperBound == candidate.string.endIndex)
                }
            }
            if numberIsSubstring {
                redBoxes.append(visionResult.boundingBox)
            }
        }
        
        // Log any found numbers.
        numberTracker.logFrame(strings: numbers)
        show(boxGroups: [(color: UIColor.red.cgColor, boxes: redBoxes), (color: UIColor.green.cgColor, boxes: greenBoxes)])
        
        // Check if we have any temporally stable numbers.
        if let sureNumber = numberTracker.getStableString() {
            showString(string: sureNumber)
            numberTracker.reset(string: sureNumber)
        }
    }
    
    override func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
            // Configure for running in real-time.
            request.recognitionLevel = .fast
            // Language correction won't help recognizing phone numbers. It also
            // makes recognition slower.
            request.usesLanguageCorrection = false
            // Only run on the region of interest for maximum speed.
            request.regionOfInterest = regionOfInterest
            
            let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: textOrientation, options: [:])
            do {
                try requestHandler.perform([request])
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Bounding box drawing
    
    // Draw a box on screen. Must be called from main queue.
    var boxLayer = [CAShapeLayer]()
    func draw(rect: CGRect, color: CGColor) {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.opacity = 0.5
        layer.borderColor = color
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.frame = rect
        boxLayer.append(layer)
        previewView.videoPreviewLayer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 1)
    }
    
    // Remove all drawn boxes. Must be called on main queue.
    func removeBoxes() {
        for layer in boxLayer {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        boxLayer.removeAll()
    }
    
    typealias ColoredBoxGroup = (color: CGColor, boxes: [CGRect])
    
    // Draws groups of colored boxes.
    func show(boxGroups: [ColoredBoxGroup]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let layer = self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer
            self.removeBoxes()
            for boxGroup in boxGroups {
                let color = boxGroup.color
                for box in boxGroup.boxes {
                    let rect = layer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: box.applying(self.visionToAVFTransform))
                    self.draw(rect: rect, color: color)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

StringUtils:

```
import Foundation

extension Character {
    // Given a list of allowed characters, try to convert self to those in list
    // if not already in it. This handles some common misclassifications for
    // characters that are visually similar and can only be correctly recognized
    // with more context and/or domain knowledge. Some examples (should be read
    // in Menlo or some other font that has different symbols for all characters):
    // 1 and l are the same character in Times New Roman
    // I and l are the same character in Helvetica
    // 0 and O are extremely similar in many fonts
    // oO, wW, cC, sS, pP and others only differ by size in many fonts
    func getSimilarCharacterIfNotIn(allowedChars: String) -> Character {
        let conversionTable = [
            "s": "S",
            "S": "5",
            "5": "S",
            "o": "O",
            "Q": "O",
            "O": "0",
            "0": "O",
            "l": "I",
            "I": "1",
            "1": "I",
            "B": "8",
            "8": "B"
        ]
        // Allow a maximum of two substitutions to handle 's' -> 'S' -> '5'.
        let maxSubstitutions = 2
        var current = String(self)
        var counter = 0
        while !allowedChars.contains(current) && counter < maxSubstitutions {
            if let altChar = conversionTable[current] {
                current = altChar
                counter += 1
            } else {
                // Doesn't match anything in our table. Give up.
                break
            }
        }
        
        return current.first!
    }
}

extension String {
    // Extracts the first US-style phone number found in the string, returning
    // the range of the number and the number itself as a tuple.
    // Returns nil if no number is found.
    func extractPhoneNumber() -> (Range<String.Index>, String)? {
        // Do a first pass to find any substring that could be a US phone
        // number. This will match the following common patterns and more:
        // xxx-xxx-xxxx
        // xxx xxx xxxx
        // (xxx) xxx-xxxx
        // (xxx)xxx-xxxx
        // xxx.xxx.xxxx
        // xxx xxx-xxxx
        // xxx/xxx.xxxx
        // +1-xxx-xxx-xxxx
        // Note that this doesn't only look for digits since some digits look
        // very similar to letters. This is handled later.
        let pattern = #"""
        (?x)                    # Verbose regex, allows comments
        (?:\+1-?)?                # Potential international prefix, may have -
        [(]?                    # Potential opening (
        \b(\w{3})                # Capture xxx
        [)]?                    # Potential closing )
        [\ -./]?                # Potential separator
        (\w{3})                    # Capture xxx
        [\ -./]?                # Potential separator
        (\w{4})\b                # Capture xxxx
        """#
        
        guard let range = self.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) else {
            // No phone number found.
            return nil
        }
        
        // Potential number found. Strip out punctuation, whitespace and country
        // prefix.
        var phoneNumberDigits = ""
        let substring = String(self[range])
        let nsrange = NSRange(substring.startIndex..., in: substring)
        do {
            // Extract the characters from the substring.
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
            if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: substring, options: [], range: nsrange) {
                for rangeInd in 1 ..< match.numberOfRanges {
                    let range = match.range(at: rangeInd)
                    let matchString = (substring as NSString).substring(with: range)
                    phoneNumberDigits += matchString as String
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error \(error) when creating pattern")
        }
        
        // Must be exactly 10 digits.
        guard phoneNumberDigits.count == 10 else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // Substitute commonly misrecognized characters, for example: 'S' -> '5' or 'l' -> '1'
        var result = ""
        let allowedChars = "0123456789"
        for var char in phoneNumberDigits {
            char = char.getSimilarCharacterIfNotIn(allowedChars: allowedChars)
            guard allowedChars.contains(char) else {
                return nil
            }
            result.append(char)
        }
        return (range, result)
    }
}

class StringTracker {
    var frameIndex: Int64 = 0

    typealias StringObservation = (lastSeen: Int64, count: Int64)
    
    // Dictionary of seen strings. Used to get stable recognition before
    // displaying anything.
    var seenStrings = [String: StringObservation]()
    var bestCount = Int64(0)
    var bestString = ""

    func logFrame(strings: [String]) {
        for string in strings {
            if seenStrings[string] == nil {
                seenStrings[string] = (lastSeen: Int64(0), count: Int64(-1))
            }
            seenStrings[string]?.lastSeen = frameIndex
            seenStrings[string]?.count += 1
            print("Seen \(string) \(seenStrings[string]?.count ?? 0) times")
        }
    
        var obsoleteStrings = [String]()

        // Go through strings and prune any that have not been seen in while.
        // Also find the (non-pruned) string with the greatest count.
        for (string, obs) in seenStrings {
            // Remove previously seen text after 30 frames (~1s).
            if obs.lastSeen < frameIndex - 30 {
                obsoleteStrings.append(string)
            }
            
            // Find the string with the greatest count.
            let count = obs.count
            if !obsoleteStrings.contains(string) && count > bestCount {
                bestCount = Int64(count)
                bestString = string
            }
        }
        // Remove old strings.
        for string in obsoleteStrings {
            seenStrings.removeValue(forKey: string)
        }
        
        frameIndex += 1
    }
    
    func getStableString() -> String? {
        // Require the recognizer to see the same string at least 10 times.
        if bestCount >= 10 {
            return bestString
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func reset(string: String) {
        seenStrings.removeValue(forKey: string)
        bestCount = 0
        bestString = ""
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
}
```

Comment: The only differences I'm seeing b/w your code and the original are the border width and the view controller name. Neither of these is the source of the problem. There is something else going on. Did you build the project from scratch or are you editing their project? Are you seeing the AVCapture on screen and are you trying to recognize only printed text inside the cutout view? In short, the above works fine for me.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for checking, so glad to hear its working for you! I basically created the same swift files and made a view controller within an existing giant project. My boss just wants me to make the view controller work the same way as the apple example while ignoring everything else that is in our project for now. I'll attach some pictures above to my post to show you what is happening.. there is no red lines so I think it is just not recognizing the text where as the apple one does.

Comment: As an aside, the string cannot intersect the boundary of the `regionOfInterest` like in your second screen snapshot. That having been said, I’m sure that is not the issue here, but just an idiosyncrasy of that particular screen snapshot. On the basis of what you’ve shared thus far, I suspect some disconnect between the cutout view and where the region of interest really is. E.g., in your app, do you have a navigation bar or tab bar? Or is this view “presented” in such a way that it doesn’t take up the whole screen?

Comment: That having been said, I’ve tried a few permutations to manifest your problem, to no avail. You may need to make a copy of your project, and then rip everything unrelated to this particular issue, until you either discover the source of the problem or you have a nice, [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem that you can share with us.

Comment: @Rob Thank you! You were right about the screenshot being just an idiosyncrasy. However with some help from my boss we discovered its because I was using the wrong class on the view controller.. instead of it being TextScanViewController it should have been set to Visionviewcontroller... it was skipping a whole class. I didn't realize how classes inherited and that there was an order to them. I have a lot to learn but learning a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong class on the view controller.. instead of it being TextScanViewController it should have been set to Visionviewcontroller... it was skipping a whole class. I didn't realize how classes are inherited and that there was an important order to them. I have a lot to learn but learning a lot! :)

Comment: To clarify, I gather that the storyboard scene had specified a base class of `TextScanViewController` rather than `VisionViewController`. Yep, that would do it. I’m happy you solved the issue!